# how to set anim in loop

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to use animations in Android and I'm using the following code to run an animation:

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);
        img.setImageDrawable(null);
        AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();    
        anim.start();
```

However, this animation runs only once ! How can I run it infinitly ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code :

```
ImageView imgview= new ImageView(this);
imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.starlight);
final AnimatorSet animate = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.anim_rotate_fade);
AnimatorListenerAdapter animatorListener = new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                animate.start();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};
animate.setTarget(imgview);
animate.addListener(animatorListener);
```

Comment: Please develop your answer, or it might be considered as a low-quality answer (and deleted).

Comment: Thank i will definitely check my answer twice before posting @dici